# How can I force inheriting classes to implement a static method in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, static, methods, abstract

All I want to do is **make sure** that child classes of the class **Item** implement a **static** method and I want this to be checked at compile time to avoid runtime errors.

**abstract classes with static methods don't seem to work:**

> ERROR: A static member
>   cannot be marked as
>   override, virtual, or abstract

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public static abstract Item GetHistoricalItem(int id, DateTime pastDateTime);
}

public class Customer : Item
{
    public static override Customer GetHistoricalItem(int id, DateTime pastDateTime)
    {
        return new Customer();
    }
}

public class Address : Item
{
    public static override Address GetHistoricalItem(int id, DateTime pastDateTime)
    {
        return new Address();
    }
}
```

**and interfaces don't seem to work either:**

> ERROR: Customer does not implement interface
>   member GetHistoricalItem()

```
public class Customer : Item, HistoricalItem
{
    public static Customer GetHistoricalItem(int id, DateTime pastDateTime)
    {
        return new Customer();
    }
}

public class Address : Item, HistoricalItem
{
    public static Address GetHistoricalItem(int id, DateTime pastDateTime)
    {
        return new Address();
    }
}

interface HistoricalItem
{
    Item GetHistoricalItem();
}
```

**Is there some workaround for this to have the compiler check if inheriting classes implement a static method with a certain signature or not?**

Answer (score 22):

There is a workaround i figured out for your scenario:

```
public class Customer : Reference<Customer>, IHistoricalItem
{
}

public class Address : Reference<Address>, IHistoricalItem
{
}

public interface IHistoricalItem
{
}

public class Reference<T> where T : IHistoricalItem, new()
{
    public static T GetHistoricItem(int id, DateTime pastDateTime)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It's not producing any error even when Customer/Address isn't implementing GetHistoricItem function.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Yongke Bill Yu: why do you think it should ?

Answer (score 5):

This cannout be done.

Have a look at [Why can’t I have abstract static methods in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/why-cant-i-have-abstract-static-methods-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to force clients to implement a static method - static methods are "immutable." (There's probably a better way to describe them but that's all my mind can come up with right now!)

If some sort of overriding is required, I would consider re-visiting the design, possibly using some form of a combination of singletons and injection.

Comment: I have an class Item which various objects inherit, e.g. Customer, Address, etc. And if a class is of type Item, then I want to be able to call a factory method on it called GetHistoricalItem(). So I want to be able to say Address address = Address.GetHistoricalItem(...). And I want to know at compile time that all my classes which inherit Item do this. It should just work the same way it does for instance methods.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay this is from a long time ago, but you are better off creating some kind of History class (instance) that contains normal methods to retrieve addresses from. Register would be a good name for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems it's not possible, take a look: [Is there a way to force a C# class to implement certain static functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577749/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-c-class-to-implement-certain-static-functions)

Answer (score 0):

By definition a static method cannot be implemented in derived classes.