# Static method dependent on child class?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

How can I make the behavior of a static method dependent on the class it's called from?
E.g.

```
abstract class Base
{
    public static string GetClassName()
    { ???? }
}
class A : Base { }
class B : Base { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(A.GetClassName()); // Want to print "A"
    Console.WriteLine(B.GetClassName()); // Want to print "B"
}
```

Note that if I use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name` in `Base.GetClassName`, then "Base" is returned.

Also note that this is similar to several other SO questions, like the below, but I'm asking it in a more succinct way in order to document an answer other than "you can't":

- [Why can't I have abstract static methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/why-cant-i-have-abstract-static-methods-in-c)
- [C#, implement 'static abstract' like methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823665/c-implement-static-abstract-like-methods)
- [C# virtual (or abstract) static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763344/c-sharp-virtual-or-abstract-static-methods/763364#763364)
- [How to force abstract class childs to implement a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567042/how-to-force-abstract-class-childs-to-implement-a-static-method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# virtual (or abstract) static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763344/c-sharp-virtual-or-abstract-static-methods)

Comment: @JasonWatkins. Thanks for marking as dup. Per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314210/should-i-ask-a-new-question-in-order-to-make-the-answer-easier-to-find I should have done that

Answer (score 1):

The key is to add a type parameter:

```
abstract class Base<T>
    where T : Base<T>
{
    public static string GetClassName()
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}

class A : Base<A> { }

class B : Base<B> { }
```

This makes static members of `Base` belong to the particular class `Base<T>`, whatever `T` is. So there's no longer a single `Base.GetClassName` method, but in this case there are now two methods: `Base<A>.GetClassName` and `Base<B>.GetClassName`. Additionally, the constraint on the type parameter makes it impossible to have `class B : Base<A>`, which guarantees that `A.GetClassName` and `B.GetClassName` will return different things.

Behavior specific to child classes can be extended even further:

```
abstract class Base<T>
where T : Base<T>
{
    private static HashSet<string> values = new HashSet<string>();

    internal Base(string value)
    {
        if (Base<T>.values.Contains(value))
            throw new Exception("Not unique");
        else
            Base<T>.values.Add(value);
    }

    public static string GetClassName()
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetValues()
    {
        return new LinkedList<string>(Base<T>.values);
    }
}

class A : Base<A>
{
    public A(string value) : base(value) { }
}

class B : Base<B>
{
    public B(string value) : base(value) { }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a1 = new A("value");
    var a2 = new A("value 2");
    // var a3 = new A("value"); // Would throw an exception
    var b = new B("value"); // Does not throw an exception

    Console.WriteLine(A.GetClassName()); // Prints "A"
    Console.WriteLine(B.GetClassName()); // Prints "B"

    Console.WriteLine("The values in A:");
    foreach (var value in A.GetValues()) // This loop prints "value" and "value 2"
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The values in B:");
    foreach (var value in B.GetValues()) // This loop prints "value"
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + value);
    }
}
```

In this case, there are different static `values` objects in `Base<A>`/`A` and `Base<B>`/`B`.

All this comes with a cost, however. In the above example it's impossible for child classes of `Base` to access the same static objects without all the child classes knowing of each other *a priori*. E.g. `B` cannot access the same `values` object as `A`. One possible workaround is to use `Base<agreed-upon-type>.values` when you want all child classes to share values.